# Creating a discord bot command that responds with multiple embed fields

Tags: discord.py

I am creating a bot command that allows the user to create nice looking embeds on the server.

```
 @bot.command()
async def embed(ctx,title_str,text_str,url_str, feildname_list):
    my_embed=discord.Embed(title=title_str, url=url_str, description=text_str, color=0xFF5733)
    await ctx.send(embed=my_embed)
```

currently `feildname_list`is unused.
what i'd like to do is to create a series of inline fields using the names from fieldname list, with an ascending integer in them.

like this:

[image]

Using the documentation I found this command

```
add_field(*, name, value, inline=True)
```

which works- but felt inelegant. It feels like there should be a way of adding the fields as a key word argument when I am creating my_embed- but i can't see one in the documentation. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there isn't a way to do what you ask